# I cannot find some of my commits in git log, but I can see it using git show, why?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-push

I cannot find some of my commits in `git log`, but I can see it using `git show the-SHA1-of-commit`, or in **reflog**. I appreciate if someone know how to retrieve these commits. My team made our own git server using gitblit, and there're some commits like **"merge branch 'master' of http://example.com..."**

[image]

Comment: Please give more information. Which commits are not shown in log? give examples. And don't use bold typing for your whole text.

Comment: Your question body and title seem unrelated, perhaps you can rephrase it?

Comment: Have a look at this explanation: http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html – does that help you?

Comment: @Chronial thanks for your hint, I found similar situation http://effectif.com/git/recovering-lost-git-commits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for **Chronial**'s tip, I've learned the useful command

```
git reflog
```

which will give you a good history of what's been happening on the head of your branches, you can find the lost commit in the lists, and then

```
git cherry-pick
```

can get the lost work back.

via http://ocpsoft.org/tutorials/git/use-reflog-and-cherry-pick-to-restore-lost-commits/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the branch was merged and hence deleted.

In VS code `git status` and `git fetch` returned "everything fine", and you could see a problem only after selecting **see git log** after pushing thru VS code GUI failed.